# How to create a new dataframe with the serie of the answer ( at different times ) to a question for each user id

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm working on a dataframe with a lot of questions and some people answered several times to the inquiry. I would like to study the evolution of their answer.

I have a database that looks like:

| User ID | Time | Answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User A | 2012-01 | 5 |
| User B | 2012-02 | 6 |
| User B | 2012-01 | 5 |
| User B | 2012-03 | 6 |
| User A | 2012-02 | 5 |
| User C | 2012-03 | 6 |

And I would like to have a dataframe with the answer of each user classed by time like that:

| User ID | 2012-01 | 2012-02 | 2012-03 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User A | 5 | 6 | X |
| User B | 5 | 5 | X |
| User C | X | X | 6 |

Do you know how I could do that?

I've tried to use group by user ID but it didn't work.

Comment: Try `tidyr::pivot_wider(df1, names_from = Time, values_from = Answer)`

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyr)

# Your data
df<-read.table(text="
User ID Time    Answer
User A  2012-01 5
User B  2012-02 6
User B  2012-01 5
User B  2012-03 6
User A  2012-02 5
User C  2012-03 6",
header=TRUE) 

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Time,
              values_from=Answer)

# A tibble: 3 × 5
  User  ID    `2012-01` `2012-02` `2012-03`
  <chr> <chr>     <int>     <int>     <int>
1 User  A             5         5        NA
2 User  B             5         6         6
3 User  C            NA        NA         6
```